# Magento 2 Ui insertListing in form not submitting selected values

Tags: magento, magento2

Below is a Magento 2 ui form with a modal that when the button is clicked loads a grid of customers. The idea behind this is for the customers to be checked and the id submitted with the parent form, however the data for the selected customers is never submitted in the post data.

So if i select a few customers then submit the form after the modal closes then output the post data in the controller the customer ids are not sent along:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Tesy
    [ready_to_send] => false
    [message] => test
    [form_key] => bJBYSJKVwlJVVQmA
)
```

Here is the xml showing the modal loading the customers grid and the button with the other form fields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
                pillbox_textmessaging_campaigns_add_form.campaigns_add_form_data_source
            </item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">
                pillbox_textmessaging_campaigns_add_form.campaigns_add_form_data_source
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Campaign</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">pillbox_textmessaging_campaigns_add_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Pillbox\TextMessaging\Block\Adminhtml\Campaigns\Buttons\Save</item>

        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="campaigns_add_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Pillbox\TextMessaging\Model\Campaigns\FormDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">campaigns_add_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <modal name="customers_modal">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="onCancel" xsi:type="string">
                    actionDone
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">
                        All Customers
                    </item>
                    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="text" xsi:type="string">
                                Selected
                            </item>
                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                                action-primary
                            </item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">
                                        index = customer_listing
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="1" xsi:type="string">
                                    closeModal
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <insertListing name="customer_listing">
            <settings>
                <dataLinks>
                    <exports>false</exports>
                    <imports>true</imports>
                </dataLinks>
                <autoRender>true</autoRender>
                <selectionsProvider>
                    customer_listing.customer_listing.columns.ids
                </selectionsProvider>
                <dataScope>customer_listing</dataScope>
                <ns>customer_listing</ns>
            </settings>
        </insertListing>
    </modal>
    <fieldset name="campaign_information">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Campaign Information</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <button name="customers_button"
                component="Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                        Select Customers
                    </item>
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                        Customers
                    </item>
                    <item name="displayAsLink" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="labelVisible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">
                        ui/form/components/button/container
                    </item>
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">
                                pillbox_textmessaging_campaigns_add_form.pillbox_textmessaging_campaigns_add_form.customers_modal
                            </item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">
                                toggleModal
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </button>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Campaign Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>

        </field>
        <field name="message">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message Content</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <htmlContent name="sms_count_html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">
                Pillbox\TextMessaging\Block\Adminhtml\Shared\HtmlContent\TextFormCountHtml
            </argument>
        </htmlContent>
        <field name="ready_to_send" formElement="checkbox">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Ready To Send?</label>
                <tooltip>
                    <description translate="true">Check the box if you would like to send the campaign immediately.
                    </description>
                </tooltip>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="boolean">false</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="boolean">true</map>
                        </valueMap>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change:

```
<selectionsProvider>
                    customer_listing.customer_listing.columns.ids
                </selectionsProvider>
```

to

```
<selectionsProvider>
                    customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids
                </selectionsProvider>
```